# Nativescript Detect Focus Change On TextField - Code Behind

Tags: javascript, nativescript

So I am creating a textField through code behind in Nativescript Javascript.

I wanna create an event so when the focus on a field changes I can detect it.

I have tried:

```
textFieldName.focus = "onFocus";

function onfocus(args){
    console.log("Ping");
}
```

But nothing happens.

How do I bind the focus event through javascript, so I can detect when a field gets focus and loses focus?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have use **addEventListener** / **on** to add listener and **removeEventListener** / **off** to remove a listener.

```
textFieldObj.on(textFieldModule.focusEvent, onFocusFn);
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/events).

Comment: Actually, Manoj, in the "onFocusFn", is there anyway to tell which textFieldObj was clicked? Say If I have mutiple objs, all calling the same "onFocusFn"?

Comment: Of course, you can. The function should receive an argument of type EventData (https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/interfaces/_data_observable_.eventdata). Let's call it `args` and `args.object` will be the element that actually triggered the event.

Comment: So I'm using the listener, but it only runs when I get focus, what about when I lose it?

Comment: @TheGoldenD0nut: Losing focus is `onBlur` or `blurEvent`.

Comment: Also remember that with Android blur won't be called until another item is focused. In case if you are in the last textfield of your page, blur won't be called if you just hit return key which will just hide the keyboard.